# Organizing classes in symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

Having a lot of classes containing various groups of classes - business logic, interfaces, etc - how do I organize them in symfony 2? Do I just make all of them services and organize as service hierarchical structures? It would create a lot of dependency injections and a mess probably.

Comment: From the command line run: app/console debug:container.  As it shows, the basic framework already has hundreds of services defined.  Adding more will not, by itself, create a mess.

Answer (score 2):

You must respect the basic hierarchical structure of project symfony but for others lot of logic classes you can create a directory in root of your bundle for each type of logic.

For me I have all of this directory in root of one bundle :

- Command
- Controller
- CouchDocument
- DependencyInjection
- Document
- Entity
- Form
- Mailer
- Model
- Resources
- Security
- Tests
- Util
- Manager (lot of services)
- Listener
- Helper
- Validator
- etc....

In each of this you can create a subfolders. With this your hierarchical structure is clever, organize and speedly comprehensive.

Comment: Ok, now let's say I have to call `Document :: isXML()` from a controller - is it better to define all `Document/*` as services, or include it as a use statement and call it this way?